# Prove that the product $NK$ of two normal subgroups $N$ and $K$ of a group $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $NK=KN$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

This seemed a bit too simple, so I just wanted to get it verified.

**The Statement of the Problem:**

Prove that the product $NK$ of two normal subgroups $N$ and $K$ of a group $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $NK=KN$.

**My Approach:**

For the first part: (WTS that $gNK = NKg)$

\begin{align}
   gNK & = (gN)K & &\text{(because of associativity)} \\
   & = (Ng)K & & \text{(because $N$ is normal)} \\
   & = N(gK) & & \text{(because of associativity)} \\
   & = N(Kg) & & \text{(because $K$ is normal)} \\
   & = NKg & & \text{(because of associativity)} \\
\end{align}

Therefore $gNK = NKg$, as desired.

Now, for $NK = KN:$

Well, since $NK$ is a (normal) subgroup of $G$, it is closed under inverses, so

$$ NK = (NK)^{-1}=K^{-1}N^{-1}=KN. $$

And, that's what it's all about!

...right?

Comment: Depending on the interpretation of the question, you may also have to proof that the product set $KN$ is a subgroup of $G$ to begin with. Otherwise it looks fine to me.

Comment: @MarcPaul I think that you're right. I should probably prove that $KN$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 2):

$NK$ is generated by $nk, n\in N, k\in K$, $g(nk)g^{-1} = gng^{-1}gkg^{-1}$,
$gng^{-1}\in N$ and $gkg^{-1}\in K$ since $N$ and $K$ are normal.

$nk = kk^{-1}nk$, $k^{-1}nk\in N$ since $N$ normal, thus $nk\in KN$