# Is $NK=KN$ still even if only one of them is normal but both are still subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, products, normal-subgroups, lattice-orders

In this question [Prove that the product $NK$ of two normal subgroups $N$ and $K$ of a group $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $NK=KN$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484870/prove-that-the-product-nk-of-two-normal-subgroups-n-and-k-of-a-group-g-i), it is proved that $NK=KN$ if both $N$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of a group $G$. I think in Artin's Algebra it is proved with only one of them assumed to be normal but both are still subgroups.

Because $N$ is normal: $\forall g \in G, \forall n \in N, gng^{-1} \in N$

$$\implies \forall k \in K, \forall n \in N, knk^{-1} \in N$$

$$\implies \forall k \in K, \forall n \in N, kn \in Nk$$

$$\implies \forall k \in K, kN \subseteq Nk$$

$$KN \subseteq NK$$

Also: $\forall g \in G, \forall n \in N, g^{-1}ng \in N$

$$\implies \forall k \in K, \forall n \in N, k^{-1}nk \in N$$

$$\implies \forall k \in K, \forall n \in N, nk \in kN$$

$$\implies \forall k \in K, Nk \subseteq kN$$

$$NK \subseteq KN$$

Do I correctly prove that $NK=KN$ above and also understand the proof in Artin's Algebra? The following is a screenshot of a proof: (Kiefer Sutherland's voice)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine and you don't even need to assume that $K$ is a subgroup (you haven't used it anywhere).

Comment: Najib Idrissi, thank you! 10 minutes to accept. 00:10:00, 00:09:59, 00:09:58 (cuts to commercials)